# Replace placeholder in string with dictionary keys

Tags: python, permutation

Let's assume I have:

- a placeholder string `"aabbaaa"`
- and a dictionary: `{'A': 'a', 'B': 'a', 'C': 'b', 'D': 'a', 'E': 'b', 'F': 'a', 'G': 'b'}`.

How can I create in python all possible permutations from the dictionary keys for the placeholder string?

The expected result would, for example, be:

`AACCAAA`, `AACCAAB`, `AACCABA`, ... `AACEAA`, `AACEAA`, `AAEEAA` ... , `FFGGFFF` etc.

Comment: You can write some code to achieve this. After all your question is how can you create all the permutations. You dont show any code or effort that anyone can help you with an issue in your code

Comment: My idea was first to reverse the dictionary, so that I have something like `'a':['A','B','D'], 'b':['C','E','G']`. Then I tried with `itertools.product()`. Creating the required pattern, though, is the part where I'm stuck. I assume something like iterating over each character in the placeholder string in combination with `itertools.product()` would be the way to go. But my `python` skills are not that sophisticated.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I've rephrased the question. I assumed the tag `python` would be enough

Comment: I think your missing the point. SO is a place for help with your code, its not a free post a problem have someone right code for your service.  people including myself will be willing to help and possibly complete your code if you can at least show a minimum attempt at the problem

Comment: Sure, I will update the post to include the code I've got so far.

Comment: When you have a reversed dict, change your string into list of lists (one sub-list for each characters) and use unpacking to get the product: `itertools.product(*[rev_dict[letter] for letter in placeholder_string])` Then you have your result as list of tuples of characters - the tuples have to be merged into strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution could be:

```
    >>> import itertools
    >>> from collections import defaultdict
    >>> dict_ = defaultdict(list)
    >>> input = "ab"
    >>> _dict = {'A': 'a', 'B': 'a', 'C': 'b', 'D': 'a', 'E': 'b', 'F': 'a', 'G': 'b'}
    >>> for k,v in _dict.items():
    ...     dict_[v].append(k)
    ... 
    >>> _iterables = [dict_[character] for character in input]
    >>> output = [''.join(tup) for tup in itertools.product(*_iterables)]
    set(['BE', 'AC', 'BG', 'AE', 'AG', 'BC', 'DG', 'DE', 'DC', 'FC', 'FE', 'FG'])
```

Let me know if it helps!!

Comment: I think you missed line `dict_ = defaultdict(list)`

Comment: Ohh!! Thanks for pointing out.I have edited the answer. Thanks once again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can build all the permutation with backtracking.

At first the dict would be more useful if reversed, so do it:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
orig_str = "aabbaaa"
d =  {'A': 'a', 'B': 'a', 'C': 'b', 'D': 'a', 'E': 'b', 'F': 'a', 'G': 'b'}
reverse_d = defaultdict(list)
for k, el in d.items():
    reverse_d[el].append(k)
```

And here we have `reverse_d = {'a': ['A', 'B', 'D', 'F'], 'b': ['C', 'E', 'G']}`

Next we can write our backtracking function that for any character of the string will put the possibilities in order:

```py
def permut(orig_str, index, chars_till_now):
    if index == len(orig_str):
        print("".join(chars_till_now))
        return
    chars = chars_till_now[:]
    chars.append("")
    for possibility in reverse_d[orig_str[index]]:
        chars[-1] = possibility
        permut(orig_str, index+1, chars)
```

You can modify the function to save the permutation rather than print or pass a specific dictionary rather than use one global; it depends on what you need.

To call the function just:

```py
permut(orig_str, 0, [])
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I was trying to avoid a recursive function, though. The solution by Anand Sai seems a little bit more elegant.